# c++ adding two bool arrays

Tags: c++, boolean

I have a number as a bool array but I need to do arithmetic operations such as add and subtract and logical such as `AND` on it with other numbers similar to it. how can do this operations in C++ without need to handle all boolean-specific calculations, and do it simply.
an example:

```
bool a[10];
bool b[10];
bool c[10];
c = a + b;
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that without doing that... I mean, I don't think this is already implemented.

Comment: *how can do this operations in C++ without need to handle all boolean-specific calculations, and do it simply*

You can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

```
#include <bitset>

std::bitset<10> a(4);
std::bitset<10> b("0000001000");

std::bitset c = a.to_ulong() + b.to_ulong();

//Etc.
//You can also use
a[0] = 4; a[1] = 5; //to initialize / access
```

Comment: Ok well while we're at it he can use `int`

Answer (score 1):

[`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) can perform a binary operation on pairs of elements from two containers, and put the result into a third container. You can use [`std::logical_and`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/logical_and/), and [`std::logical_or`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/logical_or/) to get the results you want:

```
transform(a, a+10,
          b, b+10,
          c, logical_and<bool>());

transform(a, a+10,
          b, b+10,
          c, logical_or<bool>());
```